# Taking the tour on meta, when already taken on main site

Tags: bug

When I go to my [meta profile](https://stellar.meta.stackexchange.com/users/10/jake-symons) I see a link telling me to take the tour and earn my first badge.

[image]

However, I have already taken the tour on the main site, so I already have that badge, and there aren't any tours on meta sties except [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)

Is this a bug?

P.S I think its obvious where the one vote has gone with one post on the meta :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This, unfortunately, is true for *every* child meta:

> On child meta sites, new users (those who don't have a badge yet) see the message "Take the Tour and earn your first badge" in their profile page. The message is the same as on the normal Q&A sites.

[(source)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261560/295232)

The reason is probably that it's too much work to disable the Informed badge for Meta sites only.